# Can't edit GUI in Netbeans

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans-7

I'm trying to build a GUI in Netbeans (I've also installed the Opengl Pack), but every time I try to drag a component, I get this error:

```
Cannot load component class javax.media.opengl.GLCanvas 
from JAR file C:\Program Files (x86)\NetBeans 7.3.

The class could not be found. Note the class must be 
compiled and must be part of the sources or dependencies 
of the project where the target GUI form belongs to.
```

Comment: If you are trying manually to create an instance of javax.media.opengl.GLCanvas do you get any compilation error?

Comment: @ImriPersiado I've had an Eclipse project imported that I've made manually work. The problem is with the GUI Builder displayed. When I try to move any component into the display window, the error pops up every time. All I can do is compile a blank JFrame.

Comment: @ImriPersiado Seems to be a problem with GL-Anything in the GUI Builder. As long as I don't touch a GLComponent, all the other components will work. But the second I touch a GLComponent, nothing will work anymore

Comment: Have you imported all the required jar files into your project?

Comment: @MadProgrammer I was trying to create a Jogl gui from scratch with GUI Builder. Seems like I have to hard code a GLCanvas or GLPanel in

Comment: Could you sort this out? I'm having the same problem, it was working fine just an hour ago..